# .net NotImplementedException during connection to ldap server

Tags: c#, active-directory, mono, ldap

I am writing a .net web api and I need to connect to AD using LDAP. I tried to connect to online ldap server ldap.forumsys.com, but it throws NotImplementedException. 
I am using `System.DirectoryServices`

And here is my code

```
        using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.forumsys.com/dc=example,dc=com",
            "uid=tesla,dc=example,dc=com", "password"))
        {
            var obj = entry.NativeObject;
        }
```

I am using MacBook and Mono, probably there is no library in Mono or I didn't include something.

Comment: `NativeObject` is not Implemented as it would be a COM interface and that is not available in macOS/Linux: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/0af1ea70c29a66a59765183b45d6b75fa6c3d8fa/mcs/class/System.DirectoryServices/System.DirectoryServices/DirectoryEntry.cs#L378

Comment: @SushiHangover, is there a way to connect and authenticate a user in macOS/linux using LDAP?